# Why this async function blocks the processing?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm trying to understand async/await and read some articles about it, but I'm still having difficulties to understand some scenarios.

Here I have a code that blocks the processing (note I'm not using await to wait for the response):

```js
async function myAsyncFunction() {
    console.log("myAsyncFunction started");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        sleep(5000);
        console.log("myAsyncFunction finished");
        resolve("myAsyncFunction value");
    });
}

function myNormalFunction() {
    console.log("myNormalFunction started");
    sleep(2000);
    console.log("myNormalFunction finished")
    return "myNormalFunction valiue";
}

//Just a function to real block the thread
//Relax, I'll not use it in production
function sleep(delay) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}

async function main() {
    const ar = myAsyncFunction();
    const sr = myNormalFunction();
}

main();
```

The output of this code will be:

```
myAsyncFunction started
myAsyncFunction finished
myNormalFunction started
myNormalFunction finished
```

...and I was expecting

```
myAsyncFunction started
myNormalFunction started
myNormalFunction finished
myAsyncFunction finished
```

If the purpose of an async function is not block the caller returning a promise, why on this example it's not working? Is there a way to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Async still blocks unless the execution of the function is by another thread (like xhr requests, etc)

Comment: The Function is Async that is why it is running an independent Thread. If you will use await the other will not run until it will finish the previous response.

Comment: @SalilSharma did you ran the code? I'm not using await and the code is still being blocked by the async function.

Comment: @SalilSharma — It is **not** running on an independant thread.

Comment: Two things (1) your `sleep()` function is blocking, (2) code in a `new Promise()` constructor runs synchronously. The observed behaviour should be 100% expected.